# MySQL FIND_IN_SET OR IN only work for first integer?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

This is not Duplicate question and I have read all other answer mention by my search title.

I have MySQL query that should fiend integer value from table field '**employee_id**'.

My table: 
[image]

My Query is:

```
SELECT `task_allotment`.`task_id`, `task_allotment`.`sub_proj`, `task_allotment`.`project_id`, `task_allotment`.`task_name`, `task_allotment`.`task_date`, `task_allotment`.`task_status`, `task_allotment`.`assign_by`, `project`.`provider_id` FROM `task_allotment` INNER JOIN `project` ON `task_allotment`.`project_id` = `project`.`project_id` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(9, `task_allotment`.`employee_id`) && `task_allotment`.`task_status` !="Complete" ORDER BY `task_allotment`.`task_id` DESC
```

It return empty result:
[image]

It work for first integer only but not working with any other integer.
**example:**

if Query is:

```
SELECT `task_allotment`.`task_id`, `task_allotment`.`sub_proj`, `task_allotment`.`project_id`, `task_allotment`.`task_name`, `task_allotment`.`task_date`, `task_allotment`.`task_status`, `task_allotment`.`assign_by`, `project`.`provider_id` FROM `task_allotment` LEFT JOIN `project` ON `task_allotment`.`project_id` = `project`.`project_id` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, `task_allotment`.`employee_id`) && `task_allotment`.`task_status` !="Complete" ORDER BY `task_allotment`.`task_id` DESC
```

It return proper result:
[image]

You can see above if I query with integer that place beginning of "**employee_id**" using "FIND_IN_SET(13, `task_allotment`.`employee_id`)" it return proper result but if I query though any other integer return empty result. I am not sure if only work for first integer?

Please guide me how I get proper result using other integer.

Comment: I like it when question start with "this is not a duplicate question" ...they usually are.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the string stored in `employee_id` is not a proper comma separated value it contains spaces after each comma that is why it won't work see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/44101).

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(5, '1, 2, 4, 5, 6'); // returns 0
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(CONCAT(' ',5), '1, 2, 4, 5, 6'); // returns index 4 but won't work for first value
FIND_IN_SET(1, REPLACE('1, 2, 4, 5, 6', ', ',',')) //  returns index 1, this will for all values
```

Its really a bad design to store relations in a single row , you should [**normalize**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data and save each tuple (task_id, employee_id)  in a single row in new table which is called as junction/pivot table, this way you won't have these issues

Comment: Thank you for your helpful suggestion. yes, I did very bad design I will do correct. I am accepting your answer because it return proper result.

Comment: @KuntalParbat you need to use replace first your column and then you can use find in set , see [updated demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/44101)

Comment: if I use str_replace(' ', '', $employee_id); or preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $employee_id) before save it then this problem will not generate right?

Comment: @KuntalParbat yes at the time of saving remove any spaces from your csv string

Answer (score 0):

If you have spaces in integers like, I can see `1, 2, 4, 5, 7,..`, then it will not work. I had same kind of problem.

**Solution:** [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replace.html) function in mysql can help. Just replace all spaces in that particular field with blank string `''`.

```
UPDATE `TABLENAME` SET `employee_id` = REPLACE(`employee_id`, ' ', '')
```

**Note:** Be careful next time while saving values with spaces.

Comment: This solution work for me. I need to remove space before it save right ?

Comment: As you have replaced spaces in database, now new records should be saved without spaces.